# Grouping consecutive elements together using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of elements like so:

`messages[i]`, where `messages[i]` may only exist for certain values of `i`. For instance `messages[0]` and `messages[2]` may exist but not `messages[1]`.

Now I would like to group together elements with continuous indices, for example if the indices for which messages existed were:

`2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20`

I would like to group them like so:

`2, 3, 4, 5`

`8, 9`

`12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17`

`20`

What would be an effective way to do so using Javascript?

**EDIT:**

```
for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
   if (messages[i].from_user_id == current_user_id) {
   // group the continuous messages together
      } else {
  //group these continuous messages together
   }
}
```

Comment: Loop over the array where i is 0 to length and test `if (i in array)` start pusing into a new array until that returns false. Then create a new array and start pushing when you get to another defined member, and so on... You may need an array to hold the generated arrays.

Comment: Let me try this and put up a fiddle.

Comment: @Nikhita I added a (short) answer that correctly looks at the sparseness of the array, not its values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a counter variable which has to be incremented and the difference between the index and the consecutive elements are the same, group them in a temporary array. If the difference is varies for two consecutive array elements, the temporary element has to be moved to the `result` and the temporary array has to be assigned a new array object.

```
var array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20];

var result = [], temp = [], difference;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (difference !== (array[i] - i)) {
        if (difference !== undefined) {
            result.push(temp);
            temp = [];
        }
        difference = array[i] - i;
    }
    temp.push(array[i]);
}

if (temp.length) {
    result.push(temp);
}

console.log(result);
# [ [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 8, 9 ], [ 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 ], [ 20 ] ]
```

Comment: your input array has completely continuous indices, it doesn't have any gaps in it!

Comment: @Alnitak maybe I didn't explain myself clearly, but the array I'm referring to does have continuous indices, so for `messages[i]`, `i` could take values from `0 to messages.length` but it isn't necessary that there would be a valid message for all values of `i`.

Comment: @Nikhita no, that bit was clear.  The problem with this answer is that his `array` value contains the _indices_ from your question, but he has treated them as being the _contents_ of the array.  It _should_ read `[undefined, undefined, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, undefined, 8, 9, ...]`.  I actually made the same mistake myself initially when trying to see if I could come up with a funky solution using `reduce`.

Comment: @Nikhita I think I get what Alnitak is saying. Can you please show the actual array?

Comment: @thefourtheye it's actually data coming in from an ajax request, but let me give edit the question to give you an idea of what the actual array looks like.

Comment: @Nikhita Thanks, please make sure that the array is a valid JS array.

Comment: @thefourtheye Ah! So my edit won't be of much help then.

Comment: @Nikhita Yeah, I am looking for specific and valid data. Otherwise I ll have to understand the code and come up with data on my own, which is too painful

Answer (score 4):

Given :

```
var data = [ undefined, undefined, 2, 3, 4, 5,
             undefined,undefined, 8, 9,
             undefined, undefined, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
             undefined, undefined, 20];
```

(or the almost equivalent array where the `undefined` elements don't exist at all, but where the defined elements have the same indices as above) this `reduce` call will return a two-dimensional array where each top level element is the contents of the original array, grouped by contiguously defined entries:

```
var r = data.reduce(function(a, b, i, v) {
    if (b !== undefined) {              // ignore undefined entries
        if (v[i - 1] === undefined) {   // if this is the start of a new run
            a.push([]);                 // then create a new subarray
        }
        a[a.length - 1].push(b);        // append current value to subarray
    }
    return a;                           // return state for next iteration
}, []);                                 // initial top-level array
```

i.e. `[[ 2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 9], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [20]]`

NB: this could also be written using a `.forEach` call, but I like `.reduce` because it requires no temporary variables - all state is encapsulated in the function parameters.

Comment: Given your understanding of the OP, the array should be `[,,2, 3, 4, 5,,, 8, 9, ...]`, i.e. the "undefined" members should not exist at all and will not be visited by *reduce*. However, I don't think that's what the OP meant.

Comment: @RobG my code should work whether the "missing" elements are `=== undefined` or truly missing from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the list, and if you find an element at `messages[i]`, add `i` to a list of mins.  Then, once you don't find an element at `messages[j]`, and `j` to a list of maxes.

Then you will have two lists (or one, if you use a container, as I probably would) that contains the start and stop indexes of the groups.

Comment: A container? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. An example would be great!

Comment: Have a go first, let's see what you've got.

Comment: Haha yes, I'm on it. Just didn't know what he meant by the container.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be something like this. I'm using a library called [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for my array manipulation.

Basically I'm sorting the array in ascending order. And then for every increment, I'm storing the current element to a temporary array and comparing the last value of that array to the current element if they are in sequence if not I push the values of the temporary array to my result array and so on. If my loop reaches the end I just push the values of my temporary array to my results array.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20];
arr = _.sortBy(arr, function (o) {
    return o;
});
var tmp = [];
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (tmp.length === 0) {
        tmp.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else {
        var lastEl = _.last(tmp);
        if ((lastEl + 1) === arr[i]) {
            tmp.push(arr[i]);
        }
        else {
            res.push(tmp);
            tmp = [];
            tmp.push(arr[i]);
        }
        if (i === (arr.length - 1)) {
            res.push(tmp);
            tmp = [];
        }
    }
}
// Outputs: [ [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 8, 9 ], [ 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 ], [ 20 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cluster = (arr, tmp = [], result = []) => 
    (result = arr.reduce((acc, c, i) => 
        (!tmp.length || c === (arr[i-1]+1)
            ? (tmp.push(c), acc) 
            : (acc.push(tmp), tmp = [c], acc))
            , []), tmp.length ? (result.push(tmp), result) : result)

console.log(cluster([2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20]))
```