# How to count group of consecutive numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have simple question.

forexample have an array like `int[] myArr = {1,2,3,4,9,12,17,23,34,54,55,56}` I want to count how many consecutive number groups like 1,2,3,4 is first 54,55,56 is other, total 2 concestive number groups.

Comment: I have tried attached code but I cant handle it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189541/how-to-find-the-groups-of-consecutive-elements-in-array

Comment: what counts as a group? 2+?

Comment: Yes Azro I know, I tried to convert code from js to Java, Hey Mike group of concestive numbers, how many concestive number groups I need to know in an array.

Comment: @Codcz For starters iterate through the array and check for sets of consecutive numbers and store them in other sub arrays. Keep count of those sub arrays for your scenario.

Comment: How to make array groups in Java, I mean multidimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, try to include more info on what you've tried or what you've researched. As Azro said, we're here to help, not complete tasks for you.

```
int[] myArr = {1,2,3,4,9,12,17,23,34,54,55,56};
int consecutiveSums = 0;

// Iterate through the array
for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    // Check if the next value is consecutive
    if (i + 1 < myArr.length && myArr[i] + 1 == myArr[i+1]) {
        consecutiveSums ++;
        // Skip any remaining consecutives until we reach a new set
        while (i + 1 < myArr.length && myArr[i] + 1 == myArr[i+1]) {
            i++;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(consecutiveSums);
```